# System.DirectoryServices is not recognised in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, .net, directoryservices

I'm trying to use `System.DirectoryServices` in a web site project and I'm getting this error:

> The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My project has a reference to `System.DirectoryServices` in `web.config`:

```
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
```

And I do have `using System.DirectoryServices` in the files where I want to use it.

Does anybody have a clue where to look for the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the web-server (IIS or whatever) configured to run the folder as an application (i.e. shows as a cog), and is it using the correct version of ASP.NET? If it is running as 1.1, bits of it might work - but it would fail to find that 2.0 assembly in the 1.1 GAC.

Answer (score 115):

1. Right click on References under your solution.
2. Select Add Reference.
   The reference can be found under the Framework Assemblies list.
   Select *System.DirectoryServices* and click Add.

Comment: I have it in the References and it still gives me the same error as above.

Comment: @vapcguy Old comment but you probably need to add the Reference *System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement* as well.

Comment: why cant i find System.DirectoryServices in the reference Manager?

Answer (score 10):

I think you should install Directory Services Package.

```
Install-Package System.DirectoryServices -Version 4.0.0
```

[Directory Services Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices/4.0.0)

Answer (score 8):

Shot in the dark: have you tried adding to the web.config:

```xml
<compilation debug="true">
     <assemblies>
          <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
     </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Comment: what about any assemblies that System.DirectoryServices is dependent upon?

Comment: The PublicKeyToken might need to be lower case, I think it might be case-sensitive -- I didn't have this line, and I just added it, with a copy/paste of the PublicKeyToken from the properties of my DLL in C:\Windows\Assembly (aka GAC) and that's what solved it, for me.

Comment: Even after adding the necessary references when I build the solution it got succesfully build and when I ran the project then I got the error as _CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)_ I didnt got why I got the error again after successsful build

Answer (score 7):

This is a very old thread but just to provide a complete answer for the sake of posterity ;)

This issue occurs if the project is missing a reference to the .Net Component **System.DirectoryServices**

Adding this reference in the usual manner prefered by you will resolve the issue.

Comment: It was a web site project and I did have the assembly referenced in web.config as you can see in the question.

Comment: I've ran into the same issue and I, too, have it in the references.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a web *site* project, or a web *application* project. With the latter, references are handled via the .csproj - i.e. via the "References" node in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

On Solution Explorer right-click your project, then from the resulting menu, click on Add Reference, then under the .NET tab navigate to DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to convert website to web-app.
It looks like vs failing to load the assembly should be related to versioning.
switch to `web.config` and add the assembly to it as bellow. make sure the DLL version is matching your application targeted .NET version.

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

for getting a public key you need to launch `Developer Command Prompt for VS`. Change to GAC directory related framework on above ex `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`
and call

```
sn -T System.DirectoryServices.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

These problems occur when you are working with older .net version  and trying to build with the latest IDE

It depends on which version of IDE you are using and also the current code version.

Check the web config,

In my case, I was using the Latest version i.e 4.7 and `directoryService` assembly are still referring to C#4.0.

Add below if you are using Latest version of id i.e 4.7

```
  <system.web>
  <location>

<compilation debug="false" numRecompilesBeforeAppRestart="100" targetFramework="4.7">
        <assemblies>
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
 </assemblies>
      </compilation>
</system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using Partial View/ .cshtml will will have to include the namesapce in the web.config file Under the **Views** folder (note this is not the web.config on the root directory)

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.DirectoryServices" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```