# How to Use Active Directory Authentication with a Windows Form App Written in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, ldap

I am totally new to this topic, and I've seen many other related topics about this, but how can I go about using Active Directory to validate a username and password based on which OU a user is in?

I am developing an app in Visual Studio using windows forms. Are there any libraries I need? Any preliminary details?

Again, I'm very new to this, so any and all information would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory

Comment: Yes actually. How can I include System.DirectoryServices?

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't appear to be included with my Visual Studio and I don't know what to download to get that namespace

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265096/system-directoryservices-is-not-recognised-in-the-namespace-system#14148434

Comment: If you could add your response as an actual answer I'd love to give you an upvote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate a username and password against Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290548/validate-a-username-and-password-against-active-directory)

Comment: Thanks, but the answer was already posted. I marked this question as a duplicate to aid future users.

Comment: I do have one more question though (this solution helped big time!) How can I specify by organizational unit?

Comment: `OU` is just a part of a query. Also, you can [search for questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ldap%20c%23?mode=all) here and at Google :) Usually, there are similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721696/c-sharp-ldap-query-to-retrieve-all-users-in-an-organisational-unit , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452531/querying-an-ldap